# What are the subjects of these questions?

Tags: questions, subjects

1.Do you think I did well in my Spanish examination?

2.Who won the music festival?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know here ? The subject of these questions ?  What does that mean ? It is not clear what you want here.

Comment: I need the subject of the two questions listed. can a question have a subject?

Comment: A question has a subject as any sentence. I think it's clear what is asked in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subject is generally the element with which the verb (potentially) agrees. This doesn't change just because it's a question. So in *"Do you think...?"*, *you* is the subject: if you changed it to *he*, for example, the verb would need to change the verb to *Does*. The case of *"Who won...?"* is slightly more tricky because "who" can't be pluralised in English (as opposed, say, to Spanish). But if you imagine paraphrasing as "Which person/people", you'll see that this element is the subject: *"Which person *has* come?"*, *"Which people *have* come?"*.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to understand which the subject in a question is when you look at the equivalent affirmative.

- Do you think I did well in my Spanish examination? => You think I did well in my Spanish examination.
- Who won the music festival? => Who won the music festival.

Comment: You mean _The Who_

Comment: @mplungjan +1 What? 79 people looked at this question and your comment didn't get an upvote? Wow...